# Trouble with get_tract_map function in R choroplthr

Tags: r, rstudio, choropleth, choroplethr

I've just installed the new Choroplethr v3.6.0 and am using [Ari Lamstein's blog tutorial](http://www.arilamstein.com/blog/2017/04/17/choroplethr-v3-6-0-now-cran) to practice, as well as learning R, so I'm still learning to read errors.

All the example code works for me, but when I try substituting "georgia" for "new york" I get an error:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(file_loc, exdir = cache_dir, overwrite = TRUE) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Example:

```
library(choroplethr)
packageVersion("choroplethr") 

library(ggplot2)

ny = get_tract_map("new york")
ggplot(ny, aes(long, lat, group=group)) + geom_polygon()
```

gives me my starter map.

Problem:

```
ga = get_tract_map("georgia")
```

gives me an error. I tried several other states that worked fine.

Comment: thanks for answering. it's in my text, perhaps I should include it formatted differently, but the error is: Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(file_loc, exdir = cache_dir, overwrite = TRUE) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file

Comment: Sorry, missed it somehow ... since I have to guess (cannot reproduce the problem), it sounds like the behind-the-scenes download was corrupted. Retry. If you can reproduce it, check your network settings for proxies that may be misbehaving.

Comment: i'll try redoing things now that I know it is me! thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you get an acs census api key?

Comment: yes, and I can get a "new york" map, and I can get "texas", "ohio", and others, but not "georgia"

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481085/tract-choropleth-in-choroplethr-v3-6-0-for-r/43617138?noredirect=1#comment74295910_43617138

Comment: `options(tigris_use_cache = FALSE)` fixed it!