# tract_choropleth in Choroplethr v3.6.0 for R

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

I'm trying to replicate the maps shown in this short example ([Choroplethr v3.6.0 is now on CRAN](http://www.arilamstein.com/blog/2017/04/17/choroplethr-v3-6-0-now-cran/?tl_inbound=1&tl_target_all=1&tl_form_type=1&tl_period_type=3&utm_source=drip&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Choroplethr%20v3.6.0%20is%20now%20on%20CRAN%21)) for California, but I'm having trouble with the *tract_choropleth* function for areas that are not in NY. I get the error message below. I'm able to import the underlying tract data for all areas, but I'm having trouble mapping the non-NY ones. Thanks in advance.

```
 # Load all packages (DONE)
 # Install api key (DONE)

 # Get Tract-Level Demographics 
    ca_stats = get_tract_demographics("california")

 # Create choropleth map with the function tract_choropleth
    ca_stats$value = ca_stats$per_capita_income
    tract_choropleth(ca_stats, "california", title = "2013 Per Capita Income\nCensus Tracts", legend="Dollars")
```

Error message returned:

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding,
>   use_iconv = use_iconv,  :    Cannot open layer In addition: Warning
>   message: In unzip(file_loc, exdir = cache_dir, overwrite = TRUE) :
>   error 1 in extracting from zip file

Comment: Duplicate (posted within minutes) of the still-unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480866/trouble-with-get-tract-map-function-in-r-choroplthr

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the tigris package that choroplethr uses to get Census tract boundaries.  That error shows up in the event of a corrupted download from the Census Bureau website.  Ari's solution will work; you can also try:

```
library(tigris)
options(tigris_refresh = TRUE)
```

This will direct tigris to re-download the shapefile from the Census Bureau website, and allow you to still use caching.  Once it is fixed, set `options(tigris_refresh = FALSE)` to control future re-downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using choroplethr.

I have never gotten this error myself, but it's possible that it relates to a caching issue with the tigris package. I say that because it looks very similar to [this](https://github.com/walkerke/tigris/issues/14) issue.

Here is the code which solved that user's problem:

```
library(tigris)
options(tigris_use_cache = FALSE)
```

That code causes tigris to not use its cache.

Please type that code into your R session and try the choroplethr code again.

Comment: Thanks -- works here, too. I also set `options(tigris_refresh = FALSE)` for future downloads as kwalkertcu suggested.